# INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sprintf confusion

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that has multiple simple inputs for a user to select information update options.  The user may not already have an updates profile defined so I am trying to user a "INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" statement.  I'm also trying to do this with sprintf to avoid possible SQL injection issues.  My problem is I can't begin to figure out how to code the SQL statement.  Here is the pertinent piece of the code.

```
$updateSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO reminders_cfg 
                    (id, day_of, day_of_advance, day_prior, default_time, week_prior, 2_week_prior, 3_week_prior, 4_week_prior, 5_week_prior, day_after, 2_week_after, 50_day_after) 
                    VALUES %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ",
                   GetSQLValueString($jeweler, "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayOf'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Advance'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Time'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['WeekPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['2WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['3WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['4WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['5WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayAfter'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['2WeeksAfter'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['50DaysAfter'], "text"));
```

This is in a PHP page done in Dreamweaver.  This is where the GetSQLValueString function comes in.  I really can't figure out what to do after the actual 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' portion to not have to duplicate all of the variables and placeholders again.  I hope that makes sense.

UPDATE:
OK.  Here is my latest attempt that is still not working.

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO reminders_cfg 
                    (id, day_of, day_of_advance, day_prior, default_time, week_prior, 2_week_prior, 3_week_prior, 4_week_prior, 5_week_prior, day_after, 2_week_after, 50_day_after) 
                    VALUES :id, :day_of, :day_of_advance, :day_prior, :default_time, :week_prior, :2_week_prior, :3_week_prior, :4_week_prior, :5_week_prior, :day_after, :2_week_after, :50_day_after
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE day_of = :day_of, day_of_advance = :day_of_advance, day_prior = :day_prior, default_time = :default_time, week_prior = :Week_prior, 2_week_prior = :2_week_prior, 3_week_prior = :3_week_prior, 4_week_prior = :4_week_prior, 5_week_prior = :5_week_prior, day_after = :day_after, 2_week_after = :2_week_after, 50_day_after = :50_day_after")
                    or die($mysqli->error);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $jeweler, PDO::PARAM_INT);      
    $stmt->bindParam(':day_of', $_POST['DayOf'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':day_of_advance', $_POST['Advance'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':day_prior', $_POST['DayPrior'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':default_time', $_POST['Time'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 9);
    $stmt->bindParam(':week_prior', $_POST['WeekPrior'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':2_week_prior', $_POST['2WeeksPrior'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':3_week_prior', $_POST['3WeeksPrior'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':4_week_prior', $_POST['4WeeksPrior'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':5_week_prior', $_POST['5WeeksPrior'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':day_after', $_POST['DayAfter'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':2_week_after', $_POST['2WeeksAfter'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':50_day_after', $_POST['50DaysAfter'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);

    $stmt->execute() or die("Insert query error: " . mysql_error());
    $stmt->close(); 
}
```

This is generating a SQL syntax error and since I'm new to this 'INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' I'm a bit stuck.  Here is the error...

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':id, :day_of, :day_of_advance, :day_prior, :default_time, :week_prior, :2_week_p' at line 3

Comment: If a dev submitted code like this to trunk, they would be in the office getting chewed out. You should take a look at PDO, and named parameters. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: And I totally agree with the comment above!

Comment: you are mixing PDO with mysqli now in your update

Comment: Why are you inserting an id? The column should be auto_increment. Also, can you post your table schema? On duplicate key update needs a primary key or unique key to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

After `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` you just put the values that you want to update and leave the ones that should stay the same intact. e.g

**pure mysql example**

```
insert into my_table(name, lastSeen, salary)
              values("Some Name", now(), 25334)
on duplicate key update salary = 25334, lastSeen = now()
```

`name` is `primary key` just for this example
now suppose that a record already exists in the db with the same name, the entry will just get updated, by changing salary and lastSeen. If it doesn't the entry will be created with the values supplied. in the first part of the statement

`insert into my_table(name, lastSeen, salary)
                  values("Some Name", now(), 25334)`

hope that helps.

**adition**
It would be good if you added in your questions the fields that you want to get updated on duplicated key, so we could answer your question by using your code.

**edit**
Okay, 
i know this is not the best formated code ever, but maybe this helps? (maybe there are syntax errors in there, but if this is what you want, you probably get the idea)

```
 $updateSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO reminders_cfg 
                (id, day_of, day_of_advance, day_prior, default_time, 
                 week_prior, 2_week_prior, 3_week_prior, 4_week_prior,
                 5_week_prior, day_after, 2_week_after, 50_day_after) 
                VALUES %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = %s, day_of = %s, day_of_advance = %s, 
                     day_prior = %s, default_time = %s, week_prior = %s,
                     2_week_prior = %s, 3_week_prior = %s, 4_week_prior = %s,
                     5_week_prior = %s, day_after = %s, 2_week_after = %s, 
                     50_day_after = %s ",
               GetSQLValueString($jeweler, "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayOf'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Advance'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Time'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['WeekPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['2WeeksPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['3WeeksPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['4WeeksPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['5WeeksPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayAfter'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['2WeeksAfter'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['50DaysAfter'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($jeweler, "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayOf'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Advance'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['Time'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['WeekPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['2WeeksPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['3WeeksPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['4WeeksPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['5WeeksPrior'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayAfter'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['2WeeksAfter'], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['50DaysAfter'], "text"));
```

Comment: I'm populating the form from the DB table and those are the default values for each of the form fields.  I really only want to change any of the fields that are different, but since these are coming from the same DB table I'm good just updating all of the fields.

Comment: Yeah.  That's what I was afraid of and actually trying to avoid.  I was wondering if the numeric referencing in the placeholders could access the same variables more than once, but either that is not the case, or I screwed it up in my code.

Answer (score -1):

You should only use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if there is one possible colliding key. In this case, I'm guessing it's ID.

You may be better off defining a Trigger. Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `reminders_cfg_duplicates` BEFORE INSERT ON `reminders_cfg` FOR EACH ROW
  DELETE FROM `reminders_cfg` WHERE `id`=new.`id`;
```

Run this once, for instance from a control panel of phpMyAdmin. The database will then automatically delete any duplicate-causing row, allowing for the insertion of the new row without having to duplicate all the values in an update.

Comment: This is pretty much pointless as REPLACE INTO does exact same without trigger